# Compare data from a MySQL table and a log file

Tags: php, mysql

My scenario is the following: I have a function that parses a log file (which has over 2000 lines) and stores a table in MySQL.

The table format is as follows (rows): id, name, realaddress, virtualaddress, bytessent, bytesreceived, time, blockedstatus. Which "blockedstatus" it is changed through user interaction and saved as "true" or "false".
If given comName is in the log and also in the MySQL table, then it means that it is "connected". If given comName is in the MySQL table but not in the log, then it means that it is "disconnected."

This log file is updated every 2 minutes, this means that every two minutes I will have to do all this checking, because:

- This file can have new comName that need to be inserted into the table.
- If comName is in the table but is not in the log, I need to score as disconnected in MySQL table.

The function will be executed every minute by crontab.

```
function ovpnParser($con, $pathlog){
$inclients = false;
$handle = fopen($pathlog, "r");
$inclients = false;
$sql2 = "SELECT comName FROM vpn";
$query2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);


while(!feof($handle)){
$line = fgets($handle, 4096);

if (substr($line, 0, 11) == "CLIENT_LIST")
 {
   if (preg_match("/CLIENT_LIST\t{1,}UNDEF(.*)UNDEF/", $line))
   {
     $inclients = false;
   }
   else
   {
    $inclients = true;
   }
 }
 if ($inclients)
 {
  preg_match("/CLIENT_LIST(.*)UNDEF/", $line, $conteudo);

  $partes = preg_split("/\t{1,}/", trim($conteudo[1]));

  $sql            = "SELECT comName FROM vpn
                     WHERE  comName = '{$partes[0]}'";
  $query          =  mysqli_query($con, $sql);
  $numeroDeLinhas =  mysqli_num_rows($query);

  if ($numeroDeLinhas == 0)
    {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO vpn (comName, realAddr, virtAddr, byR, byS, since, sinstamp, blockstatus)
            VALUES ('{$partes[0]}', '{$partes[1]}', '{$partes[2]}', '{$partes[3]}', '{$partes[4]}', '{$partes[5]}', '{$partes[6]}', 'true')";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    }
 }
 $inclients = false;
}
}
```

Comment: Are there other problems than putting the data correctly into the database?

Answer (score 0):

I just adjusted your function a little. I added the update statement in case the logentry is already in the database. Also I changed your queries to use prepared statements as they are enforcing well formatted statements.

There might be small mistakes as I am not used to mysqli, but this should show you how you can handle your problem.

```
function ovpnParser(mysqli $con, $pathlog) {
    $handle = fopen($pathlog, "r");
    $inclients = false;

    $stmtCheckIfExist = mysqli_prepare($con, 'SELECT comName FROM vpn WHERE comName = ?');
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmtCheckIfExist, "S", $comName);

    $stmtInsert = mysqli_prepare($con, 'INSERT INTO vpn (comName, realAddr, virtAddr, byR, byS, since, sinstamp, blockstatus) 
                                    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, "true")');
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmtInsert, "SSSSSSS", $comName, $realAddr, $virtAddr, $byR, $byS, $since, $sinstamp);

    $stmtUpdate = mysqli_prepare($con, 'UPDATE vpn SET blockstatus = "false" WHERE comName = ?');
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmtUpdate, "S", $comName);

    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $line = fgets($handle, 4096);
        if (substr($line, 0, 11) == "CLIENT_LIST") {
            if (preg_match("/CLIENT_LIST\t{1,}UNDEF(.*)UNDEF/", $line)) {
                $inclients = false;
            } else {
                $inclients = true;
            }
        }
        if ($inclients) {
            preg_match("/CLIENT_LIST(.*)UNDEF/", $line, $conteudo);
            $partes = preg_split("/\t{1,}/", trim($conteudo[1]));
            $comName = $partes[0];
            $realAddr = $partes[1];
            $virtAddr = $partes[2];
            $byR = $partes[3];
            $byS = $partes[4];
            $since = $partes[5];
            $sinstamp = $partes[6];

            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmtCheckIfExist);
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmtCheckIfExist);
            $numeroDeLinhas = mysqli_num_rows($result);

            if ($numeroDeLinhas === 0) {
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmtInsert);
            } else {
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmtUpdate);
            }
        }
        $inclients = false;
    }
}
```